# Use ionic and ionic2 together on locale computer

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

How use ionic and ionic2 together on locale computer? After install crashes one of the versions.

Comment: Do you have any error messages at hand and maybe details on the underlying software stack relevant to help answer? That would be greata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved, use vagrant here [box](https://github.com/AndrewDryga/vagrant-box-osx)